# Convert all MS excel worksheets in MS word to new xlsx format

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

is it possible to do this by some macro or vba script? I have word document with lot of inserted excel worksheets in excel 2003 format. I would like to convert them in new format. How can i automate this process?

I can do this by clicking each window and choosing option converts, but its very slow.

Comment: Please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What problem is this causing?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate Excel from Word VBA to convert files programmatically. You need to save the referenced/embedded files to the disk, open them and save in a new file format by using the [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) method where may choose the [XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat). Then you can re-embed the files in a new format.

Also if you deal with a Word open XML document you may consider using the Open XML SDK for customizing/updating the Word document, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.